# Occassional ECONNREFUSED errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I just got started with nodejs and using it to create a server. Clients connect to it using socket.io, receive jobs to proceess, and send the results back to the nodejs server.

However the server will crash occassionally with the following error:

```
node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:614:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:605:18)
```

I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: Would you be able to share your source code at all?

Comment: Where is a good place to post the source? I want to be able to take it down after a while though

Comment: We mean posting blocks of code that's related to the error. Seeing that you have 1k reputation, I'm surprised you're not familiar with posting code examples.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I am not able to tell which part of my code is causing the error. `net.js` probably came with node.js and isnt written by me...

Answer (score 3):

ECONNREFUSED means you tried to make a connection to another machine but your connection was refused - either no one was listening or a firewall blocked you.

I have seen this using http, but I think it could also happen using straight sockets.

Comment: A firewall would typically produce a timeout, not `ECONNREFUSED`

Comment: I have got ECONNREFUSED by my firewall at work. However your situation may be different

Comment: I've worked with dozens of firewalls - most will blackhole inbound traffic, not send back a fake `ECONNREFUSED`.

Comment: What do you think could have caused the client to send `ECONNREFUSED`? A system restart?

Comment: Actually, I just got one because my http server I was trying to connect to wasn't running... meaning no one was listening

Comment: If the firewall drops your SYN, you time out waiting for SYN/ACK. If the firewall rejects your SYN, you will probably get an ICMP message or a RST packet in response. I don't know, but I wouldn't be surprised if the ICMP message or RST didn't always result in ECONNREFUSED.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably struggling with node.js dying whenever the server you are calling refuses to connect. Try this:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

It will just log the errors and keep your service up and running.

Comment: Unfortunately, this quick fix can be quite dangerous. See the node docs on `uncaughtException`: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception